# Trouble With Importing Beautiful Soup in PyCharm/Python3

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pip, pycharm

[image]

1. First attempt was to add BeautifulSoup to the python interpreter in pycharm. Then import in the IDE. I received the following error. I then tried closing and reopneing PyCharm, then restarting the machine. While I am not posting my entire project here I am preforming some web scraping using Beautiful Soup.... My code on another machine in Jupyter works just fine, but I have a requirement on this machine to use PyCharm. Can anyone help?

my code was simply

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
print('hello')
```

ERROR RECIEVED:
C:\Users\sherian\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/sherian/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py
hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/sherian/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 2, in 
from bs4 import beautifulsoup
ImportError: cannot import name 'beautifulsoup' from 'bs4' (C:\Users\sherian\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\bs4_*init*_.py)

Process finished with exit code 1

[image: showing library imports in Pycharm]

Comment: @bad_coder I am not sure this answers the question. So is this file path for bueatifulsoup4 inapporpiate... see screenshot below I highlighted the package in pycharm interpreter..., ive added the screenshot to main post

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you start a new project ,try to create a virtual environment in python first and then install all the required packages in it. Then run your project your problem will get automatically solved.

Comment: do you have any links to how to start a virtual environment?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#:~:text=A%20virtual%20environment%20is%20a,part%20of%20your%20operating%20system.

Comment: follow this link :  create virtual env, activate it , install beautifulsoup in it and then run it.